# Vue + Flask: Simple Groceries List example not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jinja2

I'm doing this example from VUE.js website for a list of groceries. Although I'm getting some behavior out of the components, it is not fully working and I've exhausted all my options here to try and debug it, so I resort to your endless wisdom:

Here is what I have:

HTML:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div id="app">
  <ol>
    <todo-item
      v-for="item in groceryList"
      v-bind:todo="item"
      v-bind:key="item.id"
    ></todo-item>
  </ol>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

VUE:

```
Vue.component('todo-item', {
  props: ['todo'],
  template: '<li>[[ todo.text ]]</li>'
})

var app= new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  delimiters:     ['[[', ']]'],
  data: {
    groceryList: [
      { id: 1, text: 'Vegetables' },
      { id: 2, text: 'Cheese' },
      { id: 3, text: 'Bread' }
    ]
  }
})
```

Expected Result:

1. Vegetables
2. Cheese
3. Bread

My Result:

1. [[ todo.text ]]
2. [[ todo.text ]]
3. [[ todo.text ]]

I'm using `delimiters:     ['[[', ']]'],` to differentiate VUE's variables from the Jinja2's.

I tried replacing:
`template: '<li>[[ todo.text ]]</li>'`
by
`template: '<li>{{ todo.text }}</li>'`, but it causes Jinja2 to throw an error.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _Restrictions: This option is only available in the full build, with in-browser compilation._ So it depends on which bundle of Vue you're loading. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set delimeter in child component.